# Find out if a string contains unique characters or not

Tags: java, string, character

The code is very simple. It checks for all characters once and replaces their first occurence. However it fails for input = "aab". I don't know why.
Programming language is java.

```
 public class Solution {
 /**
 * @param str: a string
 * @return: a boolean
 */
 public boolean isUnique(String str) {
    // write your code here
    for(int i = 0; i <= 127; i++) {
        s = Character.toString((char) i);
        if(str.contains(s))
        str = str.replaceFirst(s, "");
    }
    if(str.length() == 0)
    return true;
    return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I changed the code. Now its throwing an error for input

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+
```

Error :

Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 1 ( ^ at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924) at java.util.regex.Pattern.accept(Pattern.java:1782) at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2857) at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2018) at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964) at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665) at java.util.regex.Pattern.(Pattern.java:1337) at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022) at java.lang.String.replaceFirst(String.java:2119) at Solution.isUnique(Solution.java:12) at Main.main(Main.java:11)

Comment: As of now it replaces all the character with ""(empty) and atlast `str.length()` is always 0

Comment: @TejuMB My idea is to check for every character once and replace it's first occurence. I still don't understand how  length is always 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that replaceFirst has as first argument a regular expression. So it plays havoc on `\`, `^`, `.` and others. For that you could use:

```
    str = str.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(s), "");
```

That would make from the char `"("` the pattern `"\\("`.

And at the end simply return:

```
return str.isEmpty();
```

Or you might be satisfied solely by `contains`:

```
int uniques = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 127; i++) {
    s = Character.toString((char) i);
    if (str.contains(s)) {
        ++uniques;
    }
}
return str.length() == uniques;
```

Your algorithm should work for US-ASCII.

Comment: Your answer is fabulous. Although the pattern method is not working on lintcode where I am practicing questions. Anyways the second part worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE :** As you have not mentioned the programming language you have used. I considered it as C#.

**SOLUTION :**

```
 public class Solution {
     /**
     * @param str: a string
     * @return: a boolean
     */
     public boolean isUnique(String str) {
        // write your code here
        for(int i = 0; i <= 127; i++) {
            int count = str.Split(Character.ToString((char) i)).Length - 1;
           if(count>0)
              return false;
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: language is java. I am not familiar with C# so I do not understand what you have done here

Comment: oh, i am not familiar with java standard functions of string.